# Почему таким образом не создается файл?

Tags: c, файлы

Я пытаюсь создать файл формата `".lzw"` с именем исходного. То есть из файла `"myFile.расширение"`, файл `"myFile.lzw"`использую для этого следующий код:

```
   FILE* compress (char* inputFileName){
   char * outputFileName;

   outputFileName = strtok(inputFileName, (const char*)"."); // входное имя файла разделили по точке
   outputFileName = strcat (outputFileName, ".lzw"); // добавили новое расширение
   printf ("%s", outputFileName); // Вывели в консоль
   FILE* outFile;
   outFile = fopen (outputFileName, "a"); //открыли файл в режиме "запись в конец файла"
   // сжимаем информацию из входного файла в lzw-файл...
   }
```

Однако в консоль в этом случае выводится перевод строки, а в папке с файлами не создается файла `.lzw`. При этом если написать:

```
outFile = fopen ("file.lzw", "a");
```

то такой файл создастся. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Если бы вы дали конкретные входные данные, можно было бы говорить точнее. Но

```
outputFileName = strtok(inputFileName, (const char*)".");
```

это может дать `NULL`, если точки нет, или найти не ту точку - например, если ваш путь `".\\data\\bin"` или что-то типа того.

```
outputFileName = strcat (outputFileName, ".lzw");
```

Ищите последнюю точку через `strrchr`, только еще убедитесь, что она та, что вам нужна, и собтирайте имя в новой строке, а не по старому месту.

Тут мождет просто не быть места для 4 символов - вдруг файл `"data.tx"` - что тогда?

Comment: Ну, я пока работаю с файлом .txt, Так что места должно хватить, а по поводу точки, текстовый файл лежит в той же папке, что и exe.