# Что возвращает функция strtok в моем коде?

Tags: c, строки, файлы

Я пытаюсь сделать из файла `.txt` файл `.lzw`, как уже говорил [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120317/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/1120490#1120490). Использую для этого следующий код:

```
 FILE* compress (char* inputFileName){

char * outputFileName = "";

char * ex = strchr (inputFileName, '.');

printf ("%d", ex - inputFileName + 1);

outputFileName = strtok(inputFileName, ex);

if (strtok (inputFileName, ex) == NULL ){
    printf("%s\n", "NULL Караул");
} else {
    printf("%s\n", "strtok OK");
}

outputFileName = strcat (outputFileName, ".lzw");
FILE* outFile;
outFile = fopen (outputFileName, "a");
```

Но файл не создается. Теперь я пытаюсь проверить, что вернула `strtok` В консоль не выводятся проверочные строки `NULL Караул` или `strtok OK` В таком случае `strtok` вообще не отработала? Что она вернула?

Вызываю функцию так, просто для теста.

```
 int main (){

    FILE* compressed = compress("toCompress.txt"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Файл toCompress.txt уже заранее создан в той же папке, что и exe. По поводу краша не думаю, так как кроме проверки strtok вывожу еще в консоль положение точки. Выводит `11`, что верно. Уточню, что функция возвращает выходной файл и если в переменную `outFile` записать

```
   outFile = fopen ("toCompress.lzw");
```

такой файл создастся. То есть проблема именно в функции `strtok`

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, как вы вызываете эту функцию, и что в нее передаете (похоже, что ваша программа просто крашится).

Comment: @Harry обновил вопрос

Comment: `strtok()` возвращает: [Указатель на начало маркера, если конец строки не встречается. В противном случае возвращается NULL>](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) - если нашел, что искал (разделитель) то возвращает указатель на следующий символ _отличный_ от искомого символа-разделителя (символов) или `NULL`, если не нашел или если нет подходящих _символов не разделителей_. И да, Вы неверно используете `strtok()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте займемся...

Итак, сразу: по-хорошему, строковый литерал "есть лицо неприкосновенное", его нельзя менять, так что если передаете

```
compress("toCompress.txt");
```

то используйте его как `const char *`. Одно это изменение у меня на Visual C++ перестало вызывать крэш программы.

```
char s[] = "toCompress.txt";
compress(s);
```

или

```
compress(const char* inputFileName)
```

Но идем дальше. Что вы получаете вот тут

```
char * ex = strchr (inputFileName, '.');
```

Вы получаете `ex` как указатель на строку `.txt`, т.е. `strtok` считает разделителями символы точка `.`, `t` и `x`. И, понятно,

```
strtok(inputFileName, ex);
```

обрывает вас на первом же символе `t`. Вы получаете `outputFileName`, равный

```
oCompress
```

После прибавления - **но только если вы передаете не строковый литерал, а массив!** иначе - крэш программы!! - вы получите в `outputFileName`

```
oCompress.lzw
```

И то, надо обязательно озаботиться, чтоб хватало места для добавляемого текста!

Итак, самая главная ваша ошибка - работа со строковым литералом как с `char*`, второстепенная - непонимание, как правильно работает `strtok`.

**Update**

Вот примерно как надо:

```
FILE* compress (const char* inputFileName)
{
    char* out = malloc(strlen(inputFileName)+5); // Для расширения и \0
    strcpy(out,inputFileName);
    char * ex = strrchr(out, '.');
    if (ex) strcpy(ex,".lzw");
    else strcat(out,".lzw");

    FILE* outFile;
    outFile = fopen(out, "a");

    free(out);

    //.....

    return outFile;

}
```

Comment: Хорошо. Я могу передать в strtok (const char* ) ".". Так как точка в пути одна, то это точно точка, после которой идет расширение. Также я изменил аргумент функции compress на const char * , что по идее должно вывести strtok Ok в консоль, но этого все равно не происходит.

Comment: Если вы передаете как `const char*`, ваша программа  не должна компилироваться! Вы не имеете права менять константную строку! У вас должна высыпаться куча предупреждений насчет того, что вы меняете `const`-строку! Для нее даже `strtok` вызывать категорически нельзя!! Вы должны передать строку, **СДЕЛАТЬ ЕЕ КОПИЮ** и работать с копией!

Comment: См. дополненный ответ, раз все вызывает такие трудности...